# How to set a textView to visible after an onClick event and Activity change?

Tags: java, android, textview, scrollview, visibility

I have three passages in my scrollview that need to each become visible after an onclick event on one of three buttons.

I have currently set them to all invisible. And since I cannot get it to work, I am only trying it out with one of the passages.

Because of this I created a private textview constant for only the first passage. But after I pass the intent to switch the activity, I also try to turn the view on that package to visible.

I have included my MainActivity.java and the xml file I used to set invisible.

```
package com.example.threebuttons;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView passage1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        passage1 = findViewById(R.id.passage_1);
    }

    public void launchPassageOne(View view) {
        passage1.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PassageActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent) ;
    }

    public void launchPassageTwo(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PassageActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent) ;
    }

    public void launchPassageThree(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PassageActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent) ;
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PassageActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passage_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="start|top"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:text="@string/passage1"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passage_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="start|top"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:text="@string/passage2"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passage_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="start|top"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:text="@string/passage3"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My program just crashes. And I cannot find any error messages.

How can I make the packages visible whenever I want the activity to change?
There are three passages that I want to each become visible for the respective button, then turn invisible if the back button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seams the three views are in the started activity. And so you can't change their visibility because they haven't been created.

Add this before you start the activity 
`intent.putExtra("passageNum", 1)`
Then call `startActivity(intent)`

In PassageAactivity onCreate do the following :

```
If (getIntent().hasExtra("passageNum") && getIntent().getExtras().getInt("passageNum") == 1)
    passage1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

And so on for the other views

Comment: Where is the PassageActivity onCreate? do you mean the super.Oncreate under passageactivity.java?

Comment: This should be added after super.onCreate

Comment: I have added that, but I get error messages for intent. The say "cannot resolve symbol intent".

Comment: Sorry I've been using Kotlin for the past while, in Java you'll need to use  'getIntent(). '

Answer (score 0):

```
passage1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

read more about views and how to modify their behavior here :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View

Answer (score 0):

Use `View.VISIBLE`, capital V, it's a integer constant from the View class. Remove the View argument from the method `launchPassageOne`:

```
public void launchPassageOne() {
    passage1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PassageActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent) ;
}
```

Comment: This still causes my program to crash when I click the first button to launch passage one.

Comment: You have to post the crash log and all other classes involved.

Answer (score 0):

[Image click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnHvd.jpg)Whatever I understood with your code I got that you are not initializing your methods in On create, whatever defined outside the On create will not be used until or unless called from  inside On create method.
Designed some code may help you understanding in a better way.
In below code, I made text views scrollable, but you can only scroll if text is too long to fill the entire textview.
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.threebuttons;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edit1;
    EditText edit2;
    EditText edit3;

    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    Button btn3;
    Button btnV;
    Button btnI;

    TextView t1;
    TextView t2;
    TextView t3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            // defining id for edit texts
            edit1=findViewById(R.id.passage_1);
            edit2=findViewById(R.id.passage_2);
            edit3=findViewById(R.id.passage_3);

            // defining id for buttons
            btn1=findViewById(R.id.button_1);
            btn2=findViewById(R.id.button_2);
            btn3=findViewById(R.id.button_3);
            btnV=findViewById(R.id.btnvisi);
            btnI=findViewById(R.id.btninvisi);

            // defining id for text views
            t1=findViewById(R.id.textview1);
            t2=findViewById(R.id.textview2);
            t3=findViewById(R.id.textview3);

            // making text views scrollable

            t1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            t2.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            t3.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    t1.setText(edit1.getText().toString());

                }
            });
            btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    t2.setText(edit2.getText().toString());
                }
            });

            btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    t3.setText(edit3.getText().toString());

                }
            });

            btnV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //Making passages Visible
                    t1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    t2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    t3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

            btnI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    t1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    t2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    t3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
            });

    }
}
```

Set activitymain.xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2196F3"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passage_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="passage 1"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.043"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.016" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passage_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Passage 2"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.043"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.102" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passage_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Passage 3"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.043"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.194" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/passage_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/passage_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/passage_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/passage_3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/passage_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/passage_2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/passage_3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/passage_3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/passage_3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="319dp"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#3F51B5"
        android:hint="Passage 1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.486"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.446"
        tools:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="319dp"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#3F51B5"
        android:hint="Passage 2"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.672"
        tools:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview3"
        android:layout_width="319dp"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#3F51B5"
        android:hint="Passage 3"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.486"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.895"
        tools:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnvisi"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Passage Visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.036"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.299" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btninvisi"
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="passage invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.886"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope it makes you understand in a better way,
Thanks